# Web Directory Posting Problem

Tags: c#

I am making a tool for web directory submission ,which will authomatically post to the hundreds of web directories at one go.But when I post to some phpld directories they work fine ,but some of them are giving errors like:-

1).Smarty Errors

2).Unauthorized
  Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
  Reason
  Invalid or expired submit session! Please reload submit page and try again.

Some of the Phpld directories which are giving these errors are:
1.http://www.suggest-link.net/submit.php

2.http://www.tekmarkusa.com/submit.php

3.http://www.tfwd.org/submit.php

4.http://www.thelivinglink.net/submit.php and many more.

Please help to solve these errors.Thanks

Comment: If you expect people to invest their time answering your question, YOU should invest some time in asking the question.

Comment: Thanks for your Advise Mitch .Should I give more information on this issue.Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust your application so that the submit routine submits the urls according to the rules of the directory website.

Comment: Thanks.I am making the same post data and using the appropriate Url to post to.But inspite its not working.Althought it is working for other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that as there have been new releases of phpLD that blocking submission programs like the one you are working has been something we strive to stop. The reason for this is directory owners want manual submissions, not spam or submissions that are not unique. So bear in mind there are blocking mechanisms in phpLD that prevent automatic submissions.